# Como usar/manter métodos obsoletos para versões antigas do iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, deprecated

Estou desenvolvendo um app para verões diferentes do iOS, no caso para o iOS 7 e iOS 8.
Estou tentando criar o serviço de Push Notification, porém o métodos para registrar o app e outros, estão "obsoletos".

Abaixo está o método que estou usando:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]

// obsoletos para o iOS 8
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    // Clear application badge when app launches

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: Testou? Deu certo? Já consegue aceitar e votar em alguma resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica qual a versão que esta a ser executado, e aplica o codigo para cada uma das situações

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0) {
     //Menor que iOS8
    }else{
    //Maior ou igual iOS8
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar e conforme for retorno com a resposta! rs

Answer (score 2):

Basta verificar qual método é possível utilizar no `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
// Verifica qual método utilizar com base no isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications (iOS 8)
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // Registrar para notificações iOS 8
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // Registrar para notificações iOS anteriores ao 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: Bom, mesmo usando o IF, o xcode acusa que o codigo nao é válido, e nem permte compilar.

Comment: Qual o erro? e qual versão do Xcode você esta utilizando?

Comment: Xcode 6 e iPhone 4S com iOS 8.0